# How to use keras.js for prediction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keras

I'm new to keras.js and getting a a prediction to an input with Keras.JS
I am using the following code to load and train the model

To load the JSON file :

```
async load(event)
    {
      const response = await fetch('./model.json');
      const json = await response;
      this.setState({ value: json });
      this.predictedValue = this.predictValue([this.state.value]);
    }
```

To predict:

```
 predictValue(inputs) 
   { 
      const res = new Float32Array(inputs);
      const prediction = KerasJS.model.predict(res);
      return prediction.get(0, 0);
    }
```

But the output is `[object Response]`. How can i get the predicted value?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since `predict` returns a promise (according to the [docs](https://transcranial.github.io/keras-js-docs/usage/)), you should use either

```
const prediction = await KerasJS.model.predict(inputData);
```

or `then` and `catch` methods

```
KerasJS.model.predict(res)
.then(prediction => {
// prediction is an object keyed by names of the output layers
// or `output` for Sequential models
// e.g.,
// prediction ['fc1000']
})
.catch(err => {
// handle error
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes , but I couldn't get the predicted values.